# Executing shell commands in parallel but limiting jobs (Windows without Cygwin)

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, parallel-processing, gnu-parallel

Here is what I am trying to do. Suppose I have a program called `myprogram.exe`, which I have to execute 1000 times.

Under Windows, I could usually do something as simple as:

```
for /L %n in (1,1,1000) do start /myfolder/myprogram.exe
```

However, suppose I only have 5 CPU threads I can devote to running the 1000 instances of `myprogram.exe`, such that I launch only 5, then when one of these finishes another one is launched, etc until the whole 1000 end.

Under Linux and using GNU Parallel, I could simply do:

```
seq 1000 | parallel -N0 -j5 "nohup myprogram.exe"
```

How could I achieve something like that in Windows command line? Notice that in my case using **Cygwin is not an option**, so resorting to xargs and GNU Parallel under Windows are not options either.

Comment: Can you install other software than Cygwin? E.g. WSL or Perl?

Comment: @OleTange While the ideal would be to not install other software, yes I could. I would be very interested i seeing solutions with those, in case you feel like giving an answer in that direction.

Comment: So have you tested any of the answers as yet?

Answer (score 4):

Here is a way, by using powershell to do the process count. and using a simply `set /a` as counter.

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set /a cnt=0
:counter
if !cnt! lss 1000 (
for /F "tokens=*" %%i in ('powershell ^(Get-Process -Name 'myprogram'^).count') do set proc=%%i
             if !proc! lss 5 (
                          start "C:\myfolder\myprogram.exe"
                          set /a cnt+=1
              )
    goto :counter
   )
```

You could add `echo !cnt!` in the line before `goto :counter` if you want to see it count.

It can be done without using `delayedexpansion` but I prefer to use it here.

Comment: Thanks for the contribution. While I do favor pure cmd solutions, I do work with powershell myself quite often so I will give your idea a try tonight.

Answer (score 3):

This will run five processes in parallel. Each time one of them finishes, the next process will be started (so there are always 5 of them until they all are done)

```
@ECHO off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set bunch=5

for /l %%a in (1,1,1000) do (
  call :loop 
  echo processing: %%a
  start "MyCommand" cmd /c timeout !random:~-1!
)
call :loop
goto :eof

:loop  REM waits for available slot
for /f %%x in ('tasklist /fi "windowtitle eq MyCommand"  ^| find /c "cmd.exe"') do set x=%%x
if %x% geq %bunch% goto :loop
goto :eof
```

Add the `/min` switch to `start` to minimize the started processes.
Give them a unique windowtitle (`MyCommand` here) to be able to count them.
Replace `cmd /c timeout !random:~-1!` with your actual command.

**EDIT** a slightly modified script, which may work better, if `myprogram` is a GUI (script above will work better with CLI applications):

```
@ECHO off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set bunch=5

for /l %%a in (1,1,100) do (
  call :loop 
  echo processing: %%a
  start notepad.exe
)
call :loop
goto :eof

:loop  REM waits for available slot
for /f %%x in ('tasklist /fi "imagename eq Notepad.exe"^|find /c "."') do set x=%%x
if %x% geq %bunch% goto :loop
goto :eof
```

Comment: Thanks, really appreciate it. This seems spot on, very similar to how I have been trying (and failing) to solve the issue. I will do some testing with your answer and will get back here tonight.

Comment: So, I finally had time to work with this. When I try to run your solution I get the errors `find: ‘/c’: No such file or directory` and `find: ‘cmd.exe’: No such file or directory`. Any idea how to solve that?

Comment: both running fine here. Check the type of your quotes